# Conditional attribute in jsonschema is missing in JsonData

Tags: jsonschema

I have following JSON schema

```js
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": true,   
    "if":
    {
        "properties":
        {              
            "battery":
            {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "minLength":1,
                "properties":
                {
                    "cell_composition":
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties":
                        {
                            "value":
                            {
                                "enum": ["lithium", "lithium_cobalt"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } ,
    "then":
    {
        "required": ["number_of_lithium_ion_cells"]
    }  
}
```

Below is the JSON data

```js
{
    "battery123":
    {
        "cell_composition":
        {
            "value": "lithium_polymer"
        }
    }
}
```

I got below error

Message:

> Required properties are missing from object:
>   number_of_lithium_ion_cells. Schema path:
>   #/then/required

Actually when `"battery"` attribute exist then it works fine.

when `"battery"` attribute does not exist it should give above mentioned error.

How can I add above condition then it will works on both above mentioned cases.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not totally sure I understand your expectations. Can you provide an example where you want validation to succeed and an example where you want validation to fail please? The wording of your question is currently ambigious. I'm pretty sure I will be able to help you after you've updated your question! =]

Comment: I would like to suggest that you add some computer language(s) as a tag(s). May be JavaScript? Without computer language(s) as tag(s) your question will be seen only of a few part of answerers.

Comment: Thank you for your time.
You should use this link:
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Select schema draft version 07.Put mentioned jsonschema and json data then you should get the mentioned error

Comment: I am part of the team JSON Schema spec core team. This means I write the spec now. I currently cannot understand what you are trying to do. If you can provide what I asked, I can help.

Comment: I believe I know the answer to your question, but I don't want to guess without being sure what you are asking. You haven't properly explained what "both cases" are. Please provide the JSON you want to pass and the JSON you want to fail.

Comment: JSONSCHEMA
use above mentioned jsonschema:
input JSON DATA."battery123" attribute is not exist in the json schema
expected result:
 "battery123" attribute is not exist in the schema so if should be false and it will be ignored.I want if battery not eixt in the inpt json then if then should be ignore.
Actual Result
 if condition will be executed.
 Required properties are missing from object: number_of_lithium_ion_cells. Schema path: #/then/required  
   
     { "battery123": { "cell_composition":
        {"value": "lithium_polymer" } }}

ONLINE TESTING TOOLjsonschemavalidator.net

Comment: You need to put all of that in your question, not in a wall of text in a comment. You have the ability to edit your question, and you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your both schemas with JavaScript (see snipet below) and the result is: your both schemas are absolutelly OK. You have to find your mistake not in JSON schemas.

```js
var jObj1 =
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": true,   
    "if":
    {
        "properties":
        {              
            "battery":
            {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "minLength":1,
                "properties":
                {
                    "cell_composition":
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties":
                        {
                            "value":
                            {
                                "enum": ["lithium", "lithium_cobalt"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } ,
    "then":
    {
        "required": ["number_of_lithium_ion_cells"]
    }  
}

var test1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jObj1));
console.log(test1);

var jObj2 =
{
    "battery123":
    {
        "cell_composition":
        {
            "value": "lithium_polymer"
        }
    }
}

var test2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jObj2));
console.log(test2);
```

Comment: Please use online tool for jsonschema validation jsonschemavalidator.net. and put mentioned json schema and json data in that validator it will generate the mentioned error.